# inverting function (from char to hex string)

Tags: c, hex

I need to invert this function which it's used to covert strings representing hex values to char representation

```
char * extochar(char * in, int inLen){
    int i,k;
    int resInt[inLen/2];
    char * resChar=malloc(inLen/2);

    k=0;
    for(i=0; i<inLen/2; i=i++){
        resInt[k]=chartoint(in[i*2])<<4;
        resInt[k]+=chartoint(in[(i*2)+1]);
        k++;
    }

    for(k=0; k<inLen/2;k++){
        resChar[k]=(char)resInt[k];
    }
    return resChar;
}
```

Note: Valid input are only strings consisting of 1234567890abcdef, and their length. I'm able to invert the second for cicle (quite easy) but not the first one!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is causing you problems? Also please try to clarify the functionality you want, it is quite hard to understand right now what you want.

Comment: `i=i++` in your for loop is gibberish

Comment: what is char representation? Are you looking to convert a hex string to a decimal one? look at `strtol` and `sprintf`

Comment: I'm fairly certain `i=i++` has undefined behavior.  Please don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a char pointer to your memory that you want to represent in hex form.  Allocate a char[] buffer for the string result.

Call sprintf with the formatting:

```
sprintf(stringBufferPtr, "%02hxx", charToTranslatePtr)
```

You can use some basic pointer arithmetic to cycle through stringbufferptr/chartotranslateptr in order to do multiple chars at a time if you're converting a uint64_t or something too.

Comment: it was very useful, the following actually works as i want, but i have few more doubts:
    
    unsigned char * fc = extochar("0841",4);
    int fc_len= 2; // how calculate it from fc?
    for(i=0; i< fc_len; i++){
        sprintf(stringa+2*i, "%02x", fc[i]); //magic number 2, what is it? sizeof char?
    }
the doubts are:
how calculate the length of fc?
what is the magic number 2 i guessed?
is there a way to replace extochar with a sprintf too?